# File system permissions

Tags: php, file-permissions

It was a cms and I would like to set all my files on server to -rw-------

This will make my website working as usual? or they will not read each other, for example i have this:

```
require_once 'include/checksession.php';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand what each "segment" means.

- **first triad**   what the owner can do
- **second triad**  what the group members can do
- **third triad**   what other users can do

Your permission set (`-rw-------`) only has permissions on the first triad - the owner of the file - which only has `read` and `write` permissions.

- **read**          The Read permission refers to a user's capability to read the contents of the file.
- **write**         The Write permissions refer to a user's capability to write or modify a file or directory.
- **execute**       The Execute permission affects a user's capability to execute a file or view the contents of a directory.

Therefore, the owner of the group can read the contents of the file/directory, write to the file/directory, and modify the file/directory.

Under careful file/directory ownership policies, I ***guess*** this will be okay - but I wouldn't count on it. If Apache/Nginx/... doesn't have ownership of the file, your application won't work.

This being said, I'd like to raise a few questions;

- Why change the permissions of all files/directories on your server?
- Why set a global permission rule, and not individual to each file/directory?
- What's the end-goal of this?

I'd take some consideration to [**Jon T**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24612729/3000179)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether PHP is running as your user or as as something else (Apache, nobody etc)

If it runs as your user (using suexec or something similar), then **nothing** else needs to read PHP files.

I'd set these to 0600, giving only your user read/write access. Set to 0400 (read-only) for things like config files.

If you have mutiple FTP users accessing your files, then you need to allow group read/write access as well. Permissions then would be 0660.

If PHP is running as another user and it's not in a chroot'd environment, change your webhost.

Also, on a side note, if your CMS requires permissions *anywhere* of 0777 (*I'm looking at you, Joomla*), use a different CMS