# PHP:mkdir() permission denied

Tags: php

Yesterday I've looked at all the info about this problem that i could but nothing worked. I'm getting this error:

`Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in /home/diligenceh/domains/diligencehelps.com/public_html/php_includes/form_check.php on line 32`

On line 32 I got this code:

```
if(!is_dir(__DIR__ . "/memberFiles/$id"))
    {
line 32->     mkdir(__DIR__ . "/memberFiles/$id", 0755);
    }
```

Id outputs a required number.I already got memberFiles folder in my computer and in my website.I'm using Windows 7,Apache.I'm not really good at anything with apache so if it's causing a problem(as I've read many times) please tell me more detailed help with apache.Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the user running PHP doesn't have write permissions to that directory. I'd `chmod` the folder, and (maybe - depending on the `chmod`) `chown` it, too. More info about file system permissions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612406/file-system-permissions/24612797#24612797 (Although, it's *nux based)

Comment: user which run php interpreter process can access (write priv) parent directories?

Comment: I understood what both of you,hd and itnelo wanted to say and yes,that might be the problem, but I'm not really sure how to use this chmod/chown.

Comment: @Donny have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389857/3000179

Answer (score 0):

I think this happen because of you don't have write permission.

check with this code line -

```
if(!is_dir(__DIR__ . "/memberFiles/$id"))
    {
       mkdir(__DIR__ . "/memberFiles/$id", 0777);
    }
```

and also check that $id is set correctly (folder name)

I think this will helpful  to you.

Thanks

Comment: your development environment is, Apache run on windows 7 environment.. if it is so there only two thing can be happen... **check your "memberFile" folder permission** and **check your file path is correct** you can debug your code using static path without any variables.. doing like this you can find the issue ... check your folder permission and try with static path... thanks